# Material turning black in Eevee

Tags: rendering, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I have a peculiar problem, which has been unfortunately recurring. I create a special material in nodes so I can see both textures and blend it with vertex colors. But this sometimes bugs (or maybe I set something wrong) and I have no idea how to fix it. On the picture you can see the material being applied to the object. The body of the washing machine, the door, the drum and all the buttons including the logo are all separate objects. I applied the same material on all of them, however only on the body it works at it should showing the colors. The other are black even though the UVs are set right and they all should appear as colorful as the body. When I switch to solid mode it looks as it should but under the material preview mode it turns black. This really puzzle me since there is nothing different in the setting, it is the same material, yet on the other parts it appears black and remains so even after restarting Blender.[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you correctly set the vertex color to something non-white on the black objects ?

Comment: Hmm, not really but I found a solution. When I select the black parts and switch into vertex mode, it fixes it. Weird fix, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I select the black parts and switch into vertex mode, it fixes it. Weird fix, but it works.